# How to handle xpath in SQL query while programming in Java

Tags: java, sql, xpath, ora-00933

I am trying to execute the SQL statement from my java application

Due website restriction on url I have replaced http=htp for this post.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(DID) 
  FROM (SELECT e_id DID,
               xml_doc xml, 
               rownum rn from employee_master_indexes)," +
               " table(XMLSequence(extract(xml,'//cf:SalesReport/ext:Sales/*//j:PersonAssignedIDDetails/j:PersonID/j:ID',"+ 
              "'xmlns:j=\" htp://www.it.jvp.com/xmm/3.0.3\" 
                xmlns:xsi=\" htp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" "  +   
               "xmlns:ext=\" htp://xml.crossflo.com/xdm/3.0.3/extension\" 
                xmlns:cf=\" htp://xml.crossflo.com/xdm/3.0.3\" ')))EMPID" +
              "WHERE extractValue(value(EMPID),'/j:ID', 'xmlns:j=\" htp://www.it.jvp.com/xmm/3.0.3\"')  LIKE '%-%-%' AND rn BETWEEN 999 AND 2001";
```

but end up with

> 10/05/24 11:11:51 java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   10/05/24 11:11:51  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:138)
>   10/05/24 11:11:51  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:316)
>   10/05/24 11:11:51  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:282)
>   10/05/24 11:11:51  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:639)
>   10/05/24 11:11:51  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:113)
>   10/05/24 11:11:51  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.execute_for_describe(T4CStatement.java:431)
>   10/05/24 11:11:51  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute_maybe_describe(OracleStatement.java:1029)
>   10/05/24 11:11:51  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.execute_maybe_describe(T4CStatement.java:463)
>   10/05/24 11:11:51  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1126)
>   10/05/24 11:11:51  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1274)
>   10/05/24 11:11:51  at oracle_jdbc_driver_T4CStatement_Proxy.executeQuery()

I am able to run this query properly on my sql prompt.Any guidance on what makes oracle give me this exception would be appreciated.

Comment: i tried to format your post a little better but your SQL query looks like nothing i have ever seen before! :)

Comment: Yes, I can run other SQL commands from my java code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are concatenating certain clauses to your SQL. Can you try putting it in a String and then do a system.out on it. Then take the output of system.out and trying running it exactly as is in your SQL command prompt. I bet you will quickly see the issue with the SQL there.

I second oedo, I have never seen SQL like this before!

Comment: Fixed the query problem. Had to put \ for single quote inside the XPath and extract functions.